# Parsing XML in Java from a URL

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have a webpage that has a XML document.
The URL is something like `www.snfnffn.com/pareste.xml`

The XML do I want to parse looks like:

```
<school>
   <rating value="4">"hi"</rating>
   .... <!-- more tags here -->
</school>
```

**NOTE: THE** `rating` **tag can be nested under any number of tags but it WILL ALWAYS have a** `value` **attribute**

How can I get the `value` attribute of the `rating` tag? I only want the first instance of `rating` if there are many `rating` tags in the document.

Note that the XML doc is on a URL.

I tried:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new URL(url).openStream());
```

but not sure what to do after this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes see above in op

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NodeList layerConfigList = doc.getElementsByTagName("rating");
Node node = layerConfigList.item(0);
Element e = (Element)node;
String value = e.getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: will this work even if the `rating` tag in nested in multiple tags?